# Is there a C++ allocator that respects an overridden new/delete?

Tags: c++, allocator, new-operator

I'm implementing a resource-allocating cloning operation for an array of type `T`.  The straightforward implementation uses `new T[sz]` followed by a `std::copy` call from the source into the new array. It walks memory twice.

I'd like to allocate raw memory and then use `std::uninitialized_copy` so I only walk memory once for performance reasons.  I know how to accomplish this when a custom allocator is used (`Allocator.allocate` followed by `std::uninitialized_copy`), and I know how to accomplish this using `std::allocator` (which employs `::operator new` following `lib.allocator.members` in section 20.4.1.1 of the specification).  My concern is that a `std::allocator`-based approach seems wrong for types `T` where `T::operator new` has been defined. I know I can detect such a situation using Boost.TypeTraits' `has_new_operator`.

Is there a simple, standards-compliant way to allocate-and-then-initialize raw memory in a fashion that will respect an overridden new (and does so passing over memory only once)?  If not, does using SFINAE to dispatch between an implementation employing `std::allocator` and one using the overridden operator new seem reasonable?  FWIW, grepping through Boost does not show such a use of the `has_new_operator` trait.

Thanks,
Rhys

Answer (score 4):

Seems it isn't possible. Only `operator new[]` knows how to store array size (if `T` has a destructor) in some implementation-specific way (`operator delete[]` then utilizes this info). Therefore, there is no portable way to store this information without new expression (and without calling elements constructors).

Comment: @Björn: i'm not sure, but I would prefer to use term "new[] expression" to distinguish between (possibly overloaded) "operator new" (which is simply a memory allocation function) and it "invokation" expression, which performs some additional actions such storing array size and invoking ctors

Comment: Feel free to rollback my edit. I was confused by the wording *the expression knows the size*.

Comment: It is possible to store the array size for Allocator::deallocate.  For example, with boost::shared_array one can provide a deleter class (templated argument D d) which saves the size for use at deallocate.

Comment: @Björn: expression knows..  you are right it's funny :) I'll not rollback, the subject is clear enough with comments.

Comment: @Rhys: If you are free to use some special delete procedure for your array clones (or wrap a clone with you own template class like boost shared_array), perhaps, it's possible (you may provide your own convention for storing the size and destructors invokation). But if one simply invokes delete[] dolly_array where dolly_array is _exactly_ an _array_ (not a wrapper class) then delete[] expects a number of elements stored by previous new[], usually somewhere in an extra space before the array itself, but it's not specified by the standard.

Comment: @user396672: I am using exactly the special delete procedure you discussed.  I'm not at all concerned about deallocate/delete[] semantics.

Answer (score 1):

try placement new then.

```
    typedef std::string T;
    T src[5];
    char* p = new char[sizeof(T)* 5];
    T* dest = (T*)p;
    for(int i = 0;i < 5; ++i)
    {       
        new(dest + i) T(src[i]); //placement new
    }
```

Comment: Thanks.  Dunno why placement new didn't occur to me.  I suppose I kept staring at how to do this within the standard algorithms...